# Linear algebra - inverse matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was given the question:

> " The matrices X and Y have determinants other than zero. The matrix Z is given by:
>   $Z= Y^{-1} \cdot  X \cdot  Y$
>   Decide the inverse to matrix Z expressed with the matrices X and Y"

As matrix multiplication is not commutative I can not rewrite the right side to $I\cdot X$. How do I come around this problem?

Answer (score 4):

You do the multiplication in the correct order. Namely,

$$ (Y^{-1} X Y)(Y^{-1} X^{-1} Y) = Y^{-1} X (YY^{-1}) X^{-1} Y = Y^{-1} (XX^{-1}) Y = Y^{-1}Y = I $$

so $Z^{-1} = Y^{-1} X^{-1} Y$.